# Hibernate immutable entities and dirty checking mechanism REST web app

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

It's my first project when I using ORM (Hibernate in this case). Actually I have immutable entity, what does it mean:
I fetch entity directly into DTO (using queries / projections / tuples).
Received DTOs are mapped into DB by using UPDATE clause. So generally Hibernate does not manages any entities. Another approach while updating is fetching entity then changing it's parameters using setters and commit. Actually, every POST / UPDATE request, executes SQL query, is it good or bad practice? How should I work with Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done this way.   But you have to remember that entity loaded by hibernate will be not of your class, but proxy with possible lazy loading issues
(for example, you will have to assure that all data is serialized properly  before you close that session)

There is some old reading matter (but still true):

http://www.mojavelinux.com/blog/archives/2006/06/hibernate_get_out_of_my_pojo/

Updating your data with direct issued query would give you more performmance than loadingn and then saving updatesd entity

Comment: Hmm so why people use at all hibernate's managing context? It may has lazy load issues and also performance is worse. I know it's little different question but if you could answer, what are benefits of managing entity state by setters, the one I see it's more comfortable than writing queries. And one more thing about performance, is it not faster to keep managed lets say 20 entities and then update them all in one query instead of making 20 UPDATEs queries?

Comment: It depends on what you re up to. HIbernate context is very convenient when you like to work with complex data structures, dependent entities etc.  Simple update  of  just an object without relations is better done by plain sql.   On the other side when you have complex structures and relations you are better with hibernate context.  Also - it depends on what you are up to